# wikidata api retrieve properties from entity (wikidata entry)

Tags: python, api, python-requests, wikidata

i would like to retrieve properties of a wikidata entry (eg I want to retrieve date of birth (P569) of Donald Trump (Q22686)).
I tried to use wbgetentities as action but failed to retrieve more than the description of the wikidata entry. Is it possible to retrieve the properties with wbgetentities?

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php"
    query = "Q66505"
    params = {
        'action': 'wbgetentities',
        'format': 'json',
        'languages': 'de',
        'ids': query,
        'props': 'labels|descriptions'
    }
    r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params = params)
    print(r.json())
```

I looked at the description but I could not find the solution:
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is `props=claims`: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=claims&ids=Q66505&format=json

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. @maxlath, any idea if it is also possible to display the "text" (label?) of a property? E.g., for P21 which represents gender the json file displays: "id": "Q6581072" which is female. For  P101 (occupation) it shows Q131524 (which is entrepreneur) and I would love to have the information "female" and "entrepreneur" in the json already without having to query the codes. Maybe this is also a simple add on to the query?

Comment: that's not possible in only one API query, afaik, you would need to pass by the SPARQL query service, for instance something like https://w.wiki/3VZ5